# macro definition in document body with `newcommand` inserts spaces

Tags: white-space

Sometimes I create ad-hoc macros in the middle of my document for various reasons. However, the definitions sometimes cause extra space to be inserted. My questions are:

- Why does this happen?
- How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

  Lorem ipsum
  \newcommand\dolor{dolor}
  sit amet. Lorem ipsum \dolor{} sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image: pdflatex output]

Comment: well you are inserting two spaces: one before the definition and one after it. Use % to suppress one of them. E.g. `\newcommand\dolor{sit}%`. But generally it is not a good idea to do definitions like this, your document can get very fast quite messy. Keep them in one place,

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Adding a comment at the end of the line works. I'm still confused why `\newcommand` would insert an extra space. I've learnt that TeX ignores redundant whitespace around words, including a single newline.

Comment: It doesn't insert a space. It only prevents tex to merge the two space into one. You now have <space><something><space>, and not simply <space><space>.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. How can I mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting two spaces: one before the definition and one after it (the new lines at the end).

```
 Lorem ipsum   %<--- end of line =  space
 \newcommand\dolor{dolor}  %<--- end of line =  space
 sit amet. Lorem ipsum \dolor{} sit amet.
```

Normally tex merges two spaces into one, but the `\newcommand` prevents this as you now have `<space><something><space>`, and not simply `<space><space>`, even if the `<something>` doesn't led to some visual output.

Suppress one of the spaces with %:

```
 Lorem ipsum
 \newcommand\dolor{dolor}%
 sit amet. Lorem ipsum \dolor{} sit amet.
```

Or better move the `\newcommand to a better place. Using that in the middle of a paragraph leads to messy code.